# Locate row position precisely by match function, even there are same values in different cells

Tags: excel-formula

Here is the data example

[image]

I'm trying to locate row position of column B by using match function.
However, the result is incorrect because there are same values in different cells. (which displays row "2" three times)

Please see screenshot below.

Incorrect position is highlighted with red color

[image]

Column D is the result what I expected, could someone advise how to modify my formula?
Thanks a lot!

```
=MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$19,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH will always stop at the first match.  Instead use AGGREGATE as a MIN function:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$19)/($A$1:$A$19=B1),COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1))
```